# How would I go about comparing lists with the highest length in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a program that has 4 features. The 2nd feature (selection =2) is supposed to ask the user for the amount of numbers they want. It then randomly generates the amount the user requested between the range 100-200.

The program then finds the divisors of that number, puts it into a list, counts the number of divisors in that list and then display it. The final line will display the number along with the number of divisors.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but everytime I try something, it somehow breaks the code worse.

I'm stuck on the part where I compare the divisors to see which number has the most divisors/factors. I'm not sure how to pick out the number along with the highest divisor count.

Any input would be appreaciated, thank you!

```
if selection == 2:
    numberinput = int(input("How many numbers do you want to calculate? >> "))
    while True:
        if numberinput < 0:
            print("You have entered a negative number")
            print("Please try again with a positive number")
            numberinput = int(input("How many numbers do you want to calculate? >> "))
        else:
            break

    for randomizer in range(1,numberinput+1):
        import random
        divisorRandom = random.randrange(100,201)
        divisorList=[]
        for i in range(1,divisorRandom+1):
            if divisorRandom % i == 0:
                divisorList.append(i)
                divisorCount = len(divisorList)
        print ("Number:", divisorRandom ,"\tDisivors:", divisorCount ,)
```

Comment: looks like divisorCount = len(divisorList) line should be outside inner for loop

Answer (score 0):

I think that you just want the divisor count to be stored somewhere and for that purpose you can use the dictionary,

```
    dictionary1={} #declaring dictionary
    for randomizer in range(1,numberinput+1):
        import random
        divisorRandom = random.randrange(100,201)
        divisorList=[]
        for i in range(1,divisorRandom+1):

            if divisorRandom % i == 0:
                divisorList.append(i)
                divisorCount = len(divisorList)
            dictionary1[divisorRandom]=divisorCount #storing respective number as key and its divisor count as value
        print ("Number:", divisorRandom ,"\tDisivors:", divisorCount ,)

    print(dictionary1)
```

Output:

```
How many numbers do you want to calculate? >> 3
Number: 145     Disivors: 4
Number: 133     Disivors: 4
Number: 152     Disivors: 8
{145: 4, 133: 4, 152: 8}
```